# Jquery jsonp error callback

Tags: jquery, jsonp

I am currently doing a nanodegree on udacity and in one of my project I had to make a jsonp request to wikimedia api
and it requires a jsonp request to be made on api.The project requires all api call back to have a error function.However,after several trial of error and research,i came to know that jquery doesnt invoke a error callback on jsonp request and instead  utilised a timeout workaround on ajax call.However,my code reviewers says that jquery above v2.0.  supports error callback.However,a lot of research on the topic convinces me that he is not right.And yes I checked official documentation and it says like as of jquery 1.5..error call back is not called for jsonp request.Can you guys help me out here and confirm that there is no error handling for jsonp request in any version of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

Yes,my reviewer was right.jquery 2.2.4 which I used does support jsonp request fail method.Thanks everyone.